# Use a text field to set the value of a variable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, nstextfield

I have a few NSTextFields in my XIB. I created the action for one of my text fields, and it looks like

```
- (IBAction)setXPos:(id)sender;
```

In my AppDelegate.h file, I also created an `int` named `XPos`. In my AppDelegate.m file, I am having trouble setting the value of XPos to be what I type into the text field. Any help here? Do I need to do a

```
@property
```

in my AppDelegate.h? My current code looks like this:

```
XPos = sender;
```

But it errors.

Comment: First, you don't usually set variables in AppDelegate, for what it looks you might wanna set them in your ViewController..

Comment: find some tutorials...

Comment: @NorthBlast I don't have a viewcontroller. all I have are the app delegate. This is a mac app btw

Comment: @Jason You might have done something wrong because I just created a dummy mac app and it contains/creates the ViewController.. Create new project -> OS X (Application) -> Cocoa Application -> Next -> ProjectName -> Create.. Done!

Comment: What is the IBAction Code?  Generally speaking (XPos is a float or a number), you might want to drop a number formatter in your NSTextField, but in any event getting a numeric value is easy enough.  Post the IBAction code, and we can help.

Comment: @NorthBlast is yours document based? Does it matter?

Comment: Can someone just please answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple.  In your .h file:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *xPosTextBox;
}

- (IBAction)setXPos:(id)sender;
```

Be sure you connect both to your NSTextField in IB. For the next step I'll assume you have a number formatter in the text box and that xPos is a double. In applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
[[xPosTextBox formatter] setFormat:@"##0.000"];
[xPosTextBox setDoubleValue:myInitialValue];
```

Then somewhere in your AppDelegate code add a method:

```
- (IBAction)setXPos:(id)sender
{
     xPos = [xPosTextBox doubleValue];
}
```

easy.

if you have a float in applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
[[xPosTextBox formatter] setFormat:@"##0.000"];
[xPosTextBox setFloatValue:myInitialValue];
```

Then the IBAction method:

```
- (IBAction)setXPos:(id)sender
{
     xPos = [xPosTextBox floatValue];
}
```

If you have an int (or NSInteger), no need for the number formatter, so in applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
[xPosTextBox setIntValue:myInitialValue];
// [xPosTextBox setIntegerValue:myInitialValue]; for NSInteger
```

Then the IBAction method:

```
- (IBAction)setXPos:(id)sender
{
     xPos = [xPosTextBox intValue];
    // xPos = [xPosTextBox integerValue]; for NSInteger
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a float or int?

Comment: You are the best! Apple makes the control+drag kinda confusing to a novice programmer like me.

Comment: Also, does this keep checking the value, or does it check only once (in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but where did the myInitialValue come from? Is it already defined? (it's late and ill probably implement this in the morning/after school.)

Comment: I've edited my post.  In IB if you select this text field then in the Attributes inspector you can choose when the IBAction will be called. I typically choose "Send on end editing", which will call the IBAction either when the user hits enter or tabs away from the field.

Comment: myInitialValue is just a dummy I put there.  I assume you want to set the text box to some initial value when it's first displayed.  If you've initialized xPos, you could substitute xPos for myInitialValue.